# C++ simple dictionary: list of sorted words

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    cout << "Please enter some words\n";
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; words.push_back(temp), sort(words.begin(), words.end()))
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i){
            if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i])
                cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The code must be able list of sorted words by first letter, for example I input:

```
a man a plan a canal panama;
```

and it will write:

```
    a
    canal
    man
    panama
    plan
```

Could anyone gives me advice were is my mistake in loop. I use VS 2013. Any help will be appreciated. Thank's in advance.

Comment: If you want people to help you, then at the very least format your code so it is readably.

Comment: First get input, then sort, and lastly output. Don't attempt to do it all at once.

Comment: What should the output be?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    multiset<string> words;

    for(string temp; cin >> temp; words.insert(temp))
    {
    }

    cout << endl;
    copy(words.begin(), words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if sorting logic needs a change, could use a functor in the multiset construction.